# euclidean norm expressed as a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, normed-spaces

Reading some article I have come across the following statement:
$$
\mathcal{E}\sup_{v \in S} \langle v,g\rangle = \mathcal{E} \|g\|
$$
where $g = (g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ for $g_i$ i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $S$ denotes the $\mathrm{R}^n$ sphere.

While it seems quite reasonable I couldn't prove it myself. Any ideas of a simple proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality directly yields $\langle v, g \rangle \le ||g||$ for all $v$ with $||v|| = 1$. Choosing $v = \frac{1}{||g||} g$ [if $g \ne 0$] yields the equality [note that the case $g = 0$ is trivial].

Answer (score 0):

$\langle v,g \rangle = \|v\|\|g\|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $g$. Now $v \in S$ so $\|v\|=1$. This means that $\langle v,g \rangle = \|g\|\cos(\theta)$.

Of course, the maximum value of $\cos(\theta)$ is 1 (say when $v = \dfrac{g}{\|g\|}$) so the supremum is 1. Well...this works as long as $g \not= 0$. But it is true for all non-zero $g$'s. So the expected values much match.